# Multilanguage C# forms Application with runtime language switch and customer translation edit

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, localization, runtime

I'm looking for a way to implement localization of a WinForm application containing Forms, UserControls, default Winform Controls and DevExpress controls.

There are two important requirements to this application

- possibility to change the language at runtime
- possibility for the customer to change the translation
- possibility to add a new language and new translations

Using resource.resx is not the right solution for this requirements since the resources are embedded and not possible to edit.

Maybe there is already a libary, article  or something like that available to solve this 'problem'? Otherwise what would be the best approach to handle these requirements-

Is was thinking about a database solution but i'm a little bit afraid when it comes to performance. I was thinking about something like that

- Implement BaseForm and BaseUserControl
- Implement load method iterating this.controls and getting the caption / text of all controls (also for nested controls) q: how to make sure that it is the label.text not the textbox.text
- Query database to get the translated caption
- If the queried caption is not in the database create a new row with the caption for later translation

So far its not thought through ;)

Comment: I think you need to specify whether *possibility for the customer to change the translation* means that you want customers to see or possibly even edit the translations right there in the GUI, or whether you simply want customers to be able to edit language string tables in an additional editor.

Comment: It is not necessary to change the translations directly in the GUI - because it is a "you do it only once" thing. So it is okay if we have for example an XML, CSV, DB Table containing all translations and the customer can edit the entries using an additional editor or by using excel, notepad or whatever

Comment: In that case, there's a variety of libraries available that store their localization data in external files, for example [Gettext for .NET/Mono](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gettextnet/) or [Flexible Localization](http://sourceforge.net/projects/flexiblel10n/). Are these what you are looking for?

Comment: Gettext for .NET looks like what im looking for - but i can't get it running. The point "Build resources satellite assemblies from PO files using Msgfmt.NET utility" does not work for me. Flexible Localization takes to much parameterisation (localization declaration) and so on.

Comment: I am face to face with same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Apparently not.